# bcp from remote database to local drive

Tags: sql-server

I have two database servers: `LIVE` and `DB`. Both have SQL Server 2017.

If I open SMSS in DB, I can log on to `LIVE` databases using SQL Server authentication.

My goal is to run `BCP` from `DB` to queryout from `LIVE` into a file on `DB`.

The command I'm running is:

```
BCP "Select * from <<DATABASE.dbo.TABLE>>" queryout "D:\data\test.csv" -t^ -r '0x0A' 
    -U <<USER>> -P <<PASSWORD>> -S "LIVE\MSSQLSERVER" -c -C65001
```

The problem is that for some reason I'm not connecting successfully:

> SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 87
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces:
>   Connection string is not valid [87].
>   SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 87
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
>   Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired

Am I missing something? If on `DB`, I attempt to connect to `LIVE` using SMSS, it's ok, but bcp results in not found errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using the `MSSQLSERVER` as instance name when you're trying to connect to `LIVE` here:

```
BCP "Select * from <<DATABASE.dbo.TABLE>>" queryout "D:\data\test.csv" -t^ -r '0x0A' 
    -U <<USER>> -P <<PASSWORD>> -S "LIVE\MSSQLSERVER" -c -C65001
                                   ******************
```

Normally, `MSSQLSERVER` is the internal "instance" name of the **default, unnamed** instance and you connect to such a default instance **without** providing any instance name - e.g. using just `LIVE` instead of `LIVE\MSSQLSERVER`.

Try this BCP command:

```
BCP "Select * from <<DATABASE.dbo.TABLE>>" queryout "D:\data\test.csv" -t^ -r '0x0A' 
    -U <<USER>> -P <<PASSWORD>> -S "LIVE" -c -C65001
```